# Use of exponential on columns within scala spark how to make it work

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is the code i wanted to implement . I am getting overload error . Is there a way around it ?

```
import scala.math._

dF = dF.withColumn("col2",(8.333*exp($"col1")))
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Double
```

How would one perform exponential operations like this one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use same `function` in spark as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.exp

dF = dF.withColumn("col2",exp($"col1"))
```

You are trying to use `exp` function from `scala.math` which requires `Double` but you are passing `Column` so it's not working. Spark has the same function you can use that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Umm same error occurs when you use                                                  
 dF = dF.withColumn("col2",(8.444*exp($"col1")))

Comment: Do you still get error with `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.exp`

Comment: You need to use lit for that one like `(lit(8.44) * exp($"col1"))`